# Changing arguments of function inside iter(function, sentinel)

Tags: python, python-3.x

After watching Raymond Hettinger lecture from pycon, where he demonstrate better way of "do while loop"

```
blocks = []
while True:
    block = f.read(32)
    if block == '':
        break
    blocks.append(block)
```

is equal to:

```
blocks = []
for block in iter(partial(f.read, 32), ''):
    blocks.append(block)
```

There is same structure in a code. But if arguments of function inside iter needed to be changed it doesn't work "correctly".

```
def get_data_from_user(user, type, token):
    data = []
    url = f'https://api.github.com/users/{user}/{type}?access_token={token}&page='
    i = 1
    while True:
        a = get_json_from(url + str(i))
        if not a:
            break
        data.extend(a)
        i += 1
    return data

i = 1
data = []
for piece in iter(partial(get_json_from, url+str(i)), False):
    data.append(piece)
    i += 1
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean with _it doesn't work "correctly"_?

Comment: The `url+str(i)` expression is evaluated **once**; the expression is not 'live'.

Comment: Next, you are passing in a variable not even defined outside of the function. You already handle incrementing `i` inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an important point: `iter()` takes a *static* callable object, where the arguments can't change, yet repeated calls to `f.read()` return different values. The `iter()` function with two arguments will repeatedly call `partial(f.read, 32)` (so `f.read(32)`) until the return value matches the sentinel value, and this makes reading from a file in a loop work efficiently.

Your `get_json_from()` function does *not* do this. Repeated calls to `get_json_from()` with the same arguments will not alter the return value, because `get_json_from()` doesn't have any state to fall back on.

Your arguments are not dynamic, passing in `url + str(i)` as the argument won't take `i` from the loop either, as `partial()` records the value just once:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> i = 42
>>> p = partial(str, i + 10)
>>> p.args
(52,)
>>> i = 81
>>> p.args
(52,)
>>> p()
'52'
```

The `i + 10` expression is not 'live'; the result is calculated once and passed to `partial()` as `52`; it doesn't matter that `i` is set to `81` before calling the `partial()` object.

You could use a callable object that re-calculates the arguments to `get_json_from()` each time it is called; a lambda expression would do that (taking `url` and `i` as closures from the parent scope):

```
for part in iter(lambda: get_json_from(url + str(i)), None):
    # ...
```

This calculates `url + str(i)` each time the `lambda` object is called. I am assuming `get_json_from()` returns `None` when the url doesn't exist, and not `False`.

However, in your case, you can make the code much clearer by binding 'state' like a changing `i` value to an iterable, by using a *generator function*:

```
def gen_data_from_user(user, type, token):
    url = f'https://api.github.com/users/{user}/{type}?access_token={token}&page='
    i = 1
    while True:
        a = get_json_from(url + str(i))
        if not a:
            break
        yield a
        i += 1
```

In a generator function, code is paused until you start iterating over the object that calling the function returns. When you iterate, code runs until the next `yield` expression is encountered, at which point the function code is stopped again and you are given the value of the expression.

So in the above, looping over `gen_data_from_user(....)` will give you each `a` in the `while True:` loop. The function keeps state in between with local variables, so `i` is kept around (as well as `url`) to be used for the next time the code is unpaused.

You can then use:

```
for piece in gen_data_from_user(...):
    # ...
```

No `iter()` needed, and the above is much cleaner than a `iter(lambda: ..., None)` definition.

Comment: Didn't you miss the `i += 1` in the generator?

Comment: @tobias_k: yup, cut too much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` instead of `partial` to allow re-evaluation of the variables inside every time it's called:

```
for piece in iter(lambda: get_json_from(url+str(i)), False):
```